# Chess program to know when the Queen can capture the King

Tags: c

There is this problem that i have to solve

Two pieces are placed on an 8x8 chessboard: the white king and the black queen.
Write a function that receives the positions of the King and Queen as input and determines if the Queen is in a position to eat the King.
The positions of the two pieces are identified by the row and column on which they are located, expressed as integers between 1 and 8.

Here it's the piece of code that allows the user to insert the positions of the pawns

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef  struct {
int row;
int column;
}pawn;

void position(pawn *King ,pawn *Queen);

int main (){
    pawn *King = (pawn *)malloc(sizeof(pawn));
    pawn *Queen = (pawn *)malloc(sizeof(pawn));

    printf("Inserting King's data\n");

    do {
        printf("Insert the row of the King\n");
        scanf("%d", &King->row);
    } while (King->row < 1 || King->row > 8);

    do {
        printf("Insert the column of the King\n");
        scanf("%d", &King->column);
    } while (King->column < 1 || King->column > 8);

    printf("Inserting Queen's data\n");

    do {
        printf("Insert the row of the Queen\n");
        scanf("%d", &Queen->row);
    } while (Queen->row < 0 || Queen->row > 7);

    do {
        printf("Insert the column of the Queen\n");
        scanf("%d", &Queen->column);
    } while (Queen->column < 0 || Queen->column > 7);

    position(King, Queen);

}
```

With this function the program tells that the Queen can capture the King if they're on the same raw/column

```
void position(pawn *King ,pawn *Queen){
    if (King->raw == Queen->raw) {
        printf("The Queen can capture the King\n");
    } else if (King->column == Queen->column){
        printf("The Queen can capture the King\n");
    }
}
```

There isn't any issue with the program but I need a function which allows it to say if the Queen can capture the King if they are on the same diagonal. Could you help me?

Comment: That sounds like your course assignment...  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Run this loop: `for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        
        printf("%2d-%-2d", i, j);
    }
    puts("\n");
}` It shows the index of a 2D array. Can you find any pattern in the diagonals?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer was trying to get the position value of the pawns with something like this:     `posizione1=(MAX*Re->riga)+Re->colonna;
 posizione2=(MAX*Regina->riga)+Regina->colonna;` And then trying to figure out a solution with the values that i get from this calculation

Comment: @Davide Where should i run that loop? And what this `"%2d-%-2d"` means?

Comment: Run it anywhere, inside a `main` or any function. That `%2d-%-2d` is just a weird way to put spaces, is there because initially I made the loop running till a 2 digit number, don't bother about that.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Also I've made an argument. I thought that if the King's position is 0; 0 the diagonal values will be 1; 1-2; 2-3; 3 and so on but i don't get how to convert this reasoning into code

Comment: @Davide Ok, i've runned your code and it would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: This code will not compile, `Re` and `Regina` are not defined, amongst other things

Comment: @M.M My bad, i forgot to translate that from italian to english. Now I've edited the question and translated those names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void position(pawn *King ,pawn *Queen){
    if (King->raw == Queen->raw) {
        printf("The Queen can capture the King\n");
    } else if (King->column == Queen->column){
        printf("The Queen can capture the King\n");
    } else if(abs(King->raw - Queen->raw) == abs(King->column - Queen->column)) {
        printf("The Queen can capture the King\n");
    }
    # abs - an absolute module
    # should be enough for your case, you need for loops if there are othr. pawns between them.
}
```